# Where to read from in Gakuen Heaven after the anime?

Tags: gakuen-heaven

It's a very short question but where exactly do I start reading from in the Gakuen Heaven mangas with which follows straight where the anime series finished?

I don't really want to read the mangas from the beginning and just basically want to read from where the anime series left off/finished.

Does anyone know? Thanks. :)

PS: I watched the anime series some months ago and I want to now read the manga but I just want to read from where the anime series ended. I have searched but found no very helpful results.